Elastic beanstalk nodejs application creation error
stack named 'awseb-e-3eyy2t2mmc-stack' aborted operation. current state: 'create_failed' reason: the following resource(s) failed to create: [awsebv2loadbalancer].
i'm getting this error on creating elastic bean stalk envirinment with high avaialbility option. i'm uploading zip file conatining my code
I tried 100 of times with dirrent approaches i was able to debug and solve many other errors but here i'm stuck can some one help how to  resolve this
